# Dell laptop D530 with T7500 processor: what's the fastest processor upgrade?

Tags: cpu, upgrade

I have a [Dell laptop D530](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Latitude#Latitude_D5x0_series) with a 2.2 GHz [T7500 processor](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=29761).

What's the fastest processor upgrade I can put in this laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor

Up to T7700 (2.40 GHz, 4 MB L2 Cache, 800 MHz FSB).

[Source](http://www.dell.com/us/en/corp/notebooks/latit_d530/pd.aspx?refid=latit_d530&s=corp)

Comment: @Molly: ah, ever the optimist, I see. ;)

Comment: if i were an optimist, i'd say this laptop would take an even faster CPU, but knowing Dell, you'll probably run into troubles with the BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

Just a comment on the D530 CPU, it uses a ZIF socket secured to the motherboard with a cam screw so it should be easily replaceable.

Answer (score 0):

Me thinks you've just answered your own question.

Notebook processors are usually soldered to the board, and non-upgradable. Even if it were
possible with severe desoldering and hacking, the availability of mobile processors and the extreme chance it will b0rk your entire system makes it dangerous and non-feasible.

Comment: since i have sucessfully transplanted a Pentium M 1.2 GHz into my eee pc 701 without "b0rking the entire system" or sensing any 'dangers' in the process, i'm taking offense in your last comment and will flag it accordingly.

Comment: As techs, we are prepared for these kind of operations. It is however always a danger to advise notebook CPU transplants to anyone who asked. Flag if you want - dissent leading to discourse is needed for improvement.

Comment: I happen to know Dell does not do this with their laptops. I simple ZIF socket, like joeqwerty mentions, and the heatsink are all that keeps you from your chip. I replaced a number of mother boards on this generation of dell laptop.

Comment: @prestomation: looks like it (this is a D520 which is pretty much the same laptop) http://www.parts-people.com/images/products/TF052.jpg

Comment: Please do some research into the laptop hardware being discussed, and aftermarket CPU availability, before making broad, and incorrect, generalizations. I have personally upgraded several D5xx/D6xx/D8xx Dell laptop CPU's. I use one of them daily, and have so for 2 years since the CPU upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to install a T7800 CPU into the D530? It's the fastest CPU of this product line (runs on 2.6 GHz, everything else is just like T7700). And what about the [Penryn CPUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penryn_%28microprocessor%29)? Yes, they are 45 nm (as oposed to the 65 nm T7xxx), but the [Santa Rosa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opteron#Opteron_.2890_nm_SOI.2C_DDR2.29) platform should be compatible with them...?